Retrieving the updated row after executing tx.executeSql
I am using react-native-sqlite-storage to maintain books data in my React Native app. I am using updateData() to update book's data:
async function updateData({ book_id, author, price }) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return db.transaction(tx => {
      return tx.executeSql(
        'UPDATE books SET author = ?, price = ? where book_id= ? ',
        [author, price, book_id],
        (tx, res) => {
          console.log(
            ' data updated',
            tx,
            '\nres===>',
            res,
          );
          resolve(true);
        },
        error => {
          console.log('insert data error in updateData: ', error);
          reject(false);
        },
      );
    });
  });
}

console.log() result:
data updated {"db": {"dbname": "test.db", "openError": [Function errorcb], "openSuccess": [Function errorcb], "openargs": {"dblocation": "nosync", "name": "test.db"}}, "error": undefined, "executes": [], "fn": [Function anonymous], "readOnly": false, "success": undefined, "txlock": true}
res===> {"insertId": undefined, "rows": {"item": [Function item], "length": 0, "raw": [Function raw]}, "rowsAffected": 1}

I want to get the updated row data in response. How can I do that? I tried console logging the values returned after the query is executed.

Update sql will not return the result, you need to update, then select same record. Here is an example:


db.transaction(tx => {
  tx.executeSql(
    'UPDATE table_name SET column_name = ? WHERE id = ?',
    [newValue, id],
    (tx, results) => {
      console.log('Update completed');

      // Query the updated record
      tx.executeSql(
        'SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE id = ?',
        [id],
        (tx, results) => {
          if (results.rows.length > 0) {
            const updatedRecord = results.rows.item(0);
            console.log('Updated record: ', updatedRecord);
          } else {
            console.log('Record not found');
          }
        },
        error => {
          console.log('Error during select: ', error);
        }
      );
    },
    error => {
      console.log('Error during update: ', error);
    }
  );
});



